# How to resize view height based on it's subview avalability dynamically with Autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, autolayout

I have a situation where Window has 2 subviews A and B and A view contains 2 more subviews A1 and A2. I have to show View A's height based on if A1 and A2 available or not.
Example: if A1 available then A2 not then expected A's height is A1 height + padding. and View B's height re-adjust based on vertical spacing constraints between View A and B.
- if A1 and A2 both available then A'height = A1 height + padding+ A2 height + padding. and the same B's height re-adjust based on vertical spacing constraints.

```
___________________________
| _________________________
| | A _____________________ 
| |  |_A1__________________
| |  ______________________
| | |__A2__________________
| |________________________
|
|  ________________________
| |  B
| | 
| |________________________
|
|
|__________________________


___________________________
| _________________________
| | A _____________________ 
| |  |_A1__________________
| |________________________
|
|  ________________________
| |  B
| | 
| |________________________
|
|
|__________________________
```

Comment: I figured out, I ended up calculating the height of A based on A1 and A2 view's presence, and update the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have custom your view called `LiveView` that contains all of the views as you describe. I put some code below, and explain it later.

```html
@implementation LiveView

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;
    
    // Iniitlize your view hierarchy
    
    return self;
}

+ (BOOL)requiresConstraintBasedLayout
{
    return YES;
}

// this is Apple's recommended place for adding/updating constraints
- (void)updateConstraints {
    // Define or update your constraints

    // tell constraints they need updating
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    
    // update constraints now so we can animate the change
    [self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

As you see, you should initialize your view hierarchy in the `- (id)init`. And override `+ (BOOL)requiresConstraintBasedLayout`method and return `YES`. And then override `- (void)updateConstraints` method that should define or update your constraint. When you call all the methods in method `- (void)updateConstraints` that will update your constraints and layout.

Answer (score -1):

**1. You can provide frames by using code**

`viewA1.frame = [self frameForViewA1];`

`viewA2.frame = CGRectZero;`

`viewA.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, DESIRED_WIDTH, viewA1.frame.size.height + DESIRED_PADDING + viewA2.frame.size.height);`

**2. You can use a container view**

`UIView containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, DESIRED_WIDTH, viewA1.frame.size.height + DESIRED_PADDING + viewA2.frame.size.height)];`

Then add Auto Layout constraints for view A to fit `containerView` height.

Comment: is there anyway we can get this behavior through setting constraints in interface builder? ex. if A1,A2 are UILabel and if A2 UILabel has no text then A2 has to shrink to size 0 and base on that A's height re-adjust.

Comment: Yes. By choosing 2nd option you can set Auto Layout constraints for container view by using interface builder (Storyboard/XIB).